# C# Replacing weirdness

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

I have an annoying problem with replacing in C#.
I have an array with what letter i should to replace with:

```
string[] replaceLines = format.Replace("\n", "").Split(new char[] { '=', ',' });
```

That's basically a file output that splits to array

Next a have this loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < replaceLines.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
        {
            json = Regex.Replace(json, replaceLines[i], replaceLines[i + 1]);
        }
```

That should replace it right, according to the JS

```js
function replace() {
    let area1 = document.querySelector("#text1").value;
    let area2 = document.querySelector("#text2").value.replaceAll("\n", "").split(/[=,]/g);
console.log(area2);
    for(let i = 0; i < area2.length - 1; i = i + 2) {
        area1 = area1.replaceAll(area2[i], area2[i + 1]);
    }
    document.querySelector("#text1").value = area1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BB+ sheeesh</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="atom.io/favicon.ico">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <style>
            table {
                color:deepskyblue
            }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <h1>Input</h1>
        <textarea id="text1" cols="160" rows="12"></textarea>
        <h1>Replace pattern (example: n=r, and new line, if adding more)</h1>
        <textarea id="text2" cols="160" rows="12"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button onclick="replace()">Change</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me re-writing this exact thing but with C#?
I don't know what to do, i have tried string.Replace as well

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Are you getting a different output than you expect? If so, please provide example input and expected output. How does the JavaScript and HTML relate to the problem?

Comment: You can see the JS example. I want to re-do that in C#. I'm getting only 1 letter replaced (a). So, if a=b and e=y in my described situation. "aaee" will be equal to "bbee" and not "bbyy". JS is what i'm trying to remake in Windows Forms using C#. Run the code snippet to understand what i'm trying to do

Comment: Your javascript example doesn't work here either.

Comment: A minimal code to reproduce the issue would be appreaciated.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish. Show two example texts, one before and one after the working code is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential cause of the issue your seeing in c# is your line endings. On windows they will not be `"\n"` they will probably be `"\r\n"` So I'd suggest using `Environment.NewLine` as it should automatically adjust to the environment you're running on.

Also, unless you're wanting to parse regex in your replacement swap `Regex.Replace()`, with `"string".Replace()` in your loop. Regex will probably do what you want it to do, but the Regex engine isn't necessary by the looks of it.

I'll also note, this seems to be a bare-bones replacement script. It'd be smart to validate your pattern strings.

how it's written you could potentially replace items unintentionally, for instance, if you used `a=b,b=c`, all `a`'s would become `c`'s and you'd be left with no `b`'s

Another assumption being made is there will be a comma separating each replacement pairing, so as is if you had a paring such as:

```
@"a=b
c=d"
```

you're array would end up being `["a","bc,"d"]` instead of: `["a","b","c","d"]`

Comment: Thank you for an answer! Now it outputs me exactly what i wanted!